# Eclipse HelloWorldSWT tutorial : cannot access import packages

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I recently installed Eclipse to use for an online Java course and am trying out the tutorials.

The Hello World tutorial didn't work, but I was able to make the program run with help found on Stack Overflow

The Hello World SWT tutorial doesn't work either. I was able to approximately follow the instructions, but I don't know how to run the program, I suspect because it won't compile.

The code is the following :

```
import jdk.internal.org.jline.utils.Display;

import jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell;

public class HelloWorldSWT {

    Display display = new Display();

    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    shell.setText("Hello World!");

    shell.open();

    while(!shell.isDisposed()) {

    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep(); 
} 
display.dispose();
}
```

On the left of most lines, Eclipse displays a red x, which I suspect indicates a compile error. The comments provided when hovering over the top x's indicate that it cannot access those imports, e.g.

> “The type  jdk.internal.org.jline.utils.Display is not accessible”

Hovering over that package makes comments about 'quick fixes' appear, which suggest the Display class is missing from the package.

Then I tried to do something different. I deleted the project and in the following steps I added the 'project' called Classpath i.s.o. Modulepath. (The tutorial tells to add the org.eclipse.swt.{platform}.{os}.
{arch} project, but I don't know how to do that.) I also added the main method, which I previously had forgotten. Now there only 4 x's and I can give a run command, which, among other things, produces the following output in the console :

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Users\Frank
>   Tavernier\Documents\School\eclipse-workspace\HelloWorldSWT\bin Caused
>   by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException:
>   HelloWorldSWT.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not
>   allowed in module)

Also, Eclipse still has the same complaints about the imports.

How can I convince Eclipse to run that program ?

---

01/09/2019 : Edit the question ? That seems like a terrible way to continue a discussion. Here it goes :

Thank you for the help.

I had already added a main method.

I was under the impression that Eclipse would tell the user what packages (s)he needs to import. Apparently I had misunderstood.

I imported the correct packages, but it still doesn't work.

greg-449 : “Note that you must have the appropriate SWT jar in the project class path.”
How can one convince Eclipse to put it there ?
In the package explorer there is a project with something called swt.jar in it.

Greg-449 : “You also seem to have created your Java project set up to use modules (new in Java 9 onwards). To not use modules deselect the 'create module-info.java' option on the second page of the New Java Project wizard.”
How can I get to that page ? If I type the name of my project in the wizard, the finish button remains greyed out. It seems to expect a different name, which suggests the wizard creates a new project and that the settings will not affect my existing project.

I tried to follow the tutorial again with the newly gained knowledge. I don't have a link to it. It comes with Eclipse.

At one point, even before creating the project, the tutorial says : “Open the Import wizard from the main menu via File > Import..., and select Plug-in Development > Plug-ins and Fragments. Click Next
.”
I didn't do that, because I can't find 'Plug-in Development'. However, this step of the tutorial has a 'Click to perform' link, so I clicked that in stead. That created a dialog box called 'Problem occurred' to appear, with the message : “The command did not complete successfully.” Details : “Unknown wizard: org.eclipse.pde.ui.PluginImportWizard.”
So I skipped that step.

In the New Java Project, I deviated from the tutorial to deselect 'Create module-info.java file'.

The tutorial also says : “Since our project requires SWT, we need to specify this in the project properties.”
I don't know how to do that, so I skipped that step.

I pasted the code, imported the correct packages i.s.o. the ones suggested by Eclipse. Eclipse can't find those 'correct' packages. (It could find them before (in the original project), but creating this new project changed that for some reason.)

The code is :
      import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

```
public class HelloWorldSWT {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Hello world!");
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

When I run the program, this is printed in the command window :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>     Display cannot be resolved to a type
>     Display cannot be resolved to a type
>     Shell cannot be resolved to a type
>     Shell cannot be resolved to a type
>
> at HelloWorldSWT.main(HelloWorldSWT.java:7)

Comment: Does no one have a clue how to make the Eclipse tutorial work ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post and I encountered the same problem today. Just want to share my solution here.

Firstly my eclipse is Enterprise Java Developer sversion is 2020-12(4.18.0).

When I followed the tutorial, after "*Right click in the Java editor and select Source > Organize Imports*", following two lines were added to my code

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import jdk.internal.org.jline.utils.Display;
```

The solution is:

1. replace "import jdk.internal.org.jline.utils.Display" with "import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;"
2. Right click HellowWorldSWT project, and then Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries, select "Class Path", choose "Add External JAR", then select org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64.

This solved the compilation error.

Comment: AHHH PERRO, PERO COMO LE SABIAS? JASJASJ, GRACIAS <3

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the wrong classes. The SWT classes all have `org.eclipse.swt` as the first part of the package name.

`Display` is `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display` and `Shell` is `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell`.

Note that you must have the appropriate SWT jar in the project class path.

You are also trying to use code in the class outside of a method. Java code must be in a method. Something like:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class HellowWorldSWT
{
  public static void main(final String [] args)
  {
    Display display = new Display();

    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    shell.setText("Hello World!");

    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
      {

        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
          display.sleep();

      }

    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

You also seem to have created your Java project set up to use modules (new in Java 9 onwards). To not use modules deselect the 'create module-info.java' option on the second page of the New Java Project wizard.

Comment: It still doesn't work. How can I reply to this thread to explain how/why ?

Comment: You can edit your question - click the edit link just below the question. Note that Stack Overflow does not have 'threads' - just a Question and Answers. Also add a link to the tutorial you are trying to follow.